# How to run where exists with distinct faster

Tags: mysql

I have a query with WHERE EXISTS and DISTINCT.
I just want to find distinct emails with same order_id

How can I make this faster

```
select  DISTINCT(user_email)
from (
         SELECT *
         FROM orders mto
         WHERE EXISTS
                   (
                       SELECT 1
                       FROM orders mti
                       WHERE mti.order_id = mto.order_id
                       LIMIT 1, 1
                   )
     ) as z
         INNER JOIN usermarketplaces as u ON z.ump_id = u.id
```

Comment: First: don't use >>SELECT * FROM<<.  Specify the data you want, this will make the query relatively lighter depending on the table size and number of fields.

Comment: Can you detail more about the tables, columns and index?

Comment: ... and specify table alias for EACH field in query text.

Comment: Your exists clause isn't helping. It's checking whether there's any row in mti with the same order_id as you found in mto. It's the same table, so that's literally going to always be the case. Check your logic.

Comment: That's an interesting kludge to check for dup rows!

Answer (score 0):

The usual pattern for finding dups:

```
SELECT foo
    FROM table
    GROUP BY foo
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If `foo` is indexed, it is a simple pass over the index.  Even if it is not indexed, it is a single pass over the table, plus some other grunt work.

No `DISTINCT` is needed.